# Does $f_y(0,0)=0$ for $f(x,y)=x\sqrt{|y|}$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, proof-explanation

> Does $f_y(0,0)=0$ for $f(x,y)=x\sqrt{|y|}$?

I thought we should differentiate according to the definition here:
$$
f_y=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x\sqrt{|y+h|}-x\sqrt{|y|}}{h}
$$
but the solution says the following: let's differentiate the function $f(0,y)$
which is $f(0,y)=0\cdot\sqrt{|y|}=0$ so of course $f_y=0$.

I really don't understand the logic of why we can choose an arbitrary function like that in order to calculate the derivative.

By the way, according to Wolfram Alpha the limit $f_y$ according to definition calculation doesn't [exist](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20(x*sqrt(%7Cy%2Bh%7C)-x*sqrt(%7Cy%7C))%2Fh%20as%20h%20to%200).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $f_y(x_0,y_0)$ is the derivative at $y_0$ of the function $f(x_0,\bullet)$, so the "choice" is sound (and not a choice at all). The solution is correct, because of course $f(0,y)$ is constantly $0$. The reason why wolframalpha does not get it is that it most likely first calculates $g=f_y$ in the region where it can do it symbolically - say, $\Bbb R\times (\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})$ or the likes of it - and then it tries to evaluate it at $x=0,\, y=0$. This results in the (true) remark that $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to 0} g(x,y)$ does not exists.

Comment: Nice explanation. The problem fooled me for a second. I differentiated first, plugged in later. But only for a second -- then I came to my senses.

Comment: So could one say that $f_y(a,b)=f_y(a,y)$?

Comment: @Yos I don't get what you are saying.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I was trying to generalize the conclusion from your explanation that if we need to calculate $f_y$ at point $(a,b)$ then first we get the function $f(a,y)$ and then find $f_y(a,y)$

Comment: @Yos: Not exactly. But by definition
$$f_y(a,b) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a,b+h)-f(a,b)}{h}$$

Comment: @Yos Yes. You consider the function $y\mapsto f(a,y)$ (which is a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$) and you take its derivative at $y=b$ in the one-dimensional sense.

Comment: Now I realize that I could've just plugged in the values for $x$ and $y$ straight into the limit